# Can I use cross-validation to select optimal parameters SEPARATELY?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection

I'm wondering if there is any math/stat theory out there to support or deny this idea:

I am using cross-validation and building models over a vector of parameter values to then choose the optimal value of that parameter. Can I then, decide that that is the optimal parameter value and go on to choosing the optimal value of another parameter?

More specifically, I'm using CV and repeated model fits to determine the best coefficient for the Ridge Penalty. Is it correct to then hold that Ridge Penalty coefficient constant and iterate over Lasso Penalty coefficients in order to find the best combination of the two?

Is it possible that the optimal combination of the 2 together does not include the standalone optimal values for L1 or L2 alone?

Sorry if this is confusing. Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. This will not work because of interactions between hyperparameters, which are typically nonlinear and can be very large. Optimizing each hyperparameter separately essentially assumes there is no such interaction.

Comment: ... and the Design of Experiments literature is full of discussions and examples of this (and of how to do better).